# How to Prove Distinct parallel morphisms define distinct natural transformations.

Tags: category-theory

Prove that distinct parallel morphisms $f,g: c \to d$ deﬁne distinct natural transformations $f∗,g∗: C(−,c)\Rightarrow C(−,d)$ and $f∗,g∗: C(d,−)⇒C(c,−)$ by post- and pre-composition. I have no idea how to do this. Please give me a hint. No solutions.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thank you. I will fix it. Is that better?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f_*$ and $g_*$ coincide. We can consider $C(c,c) \rightarrow C(c,d)$ and get $g = g_*(id_c) = f_*(id_c) = f$, a contradiction as $f$ and $g$ were distinct. Analogously we get what you want  for the other one.

Comment: Thank you. I wish I would of thought of that.